# I forgot the `-a`; can I restore my permissons?

Tags: permissions, file-properties

I forgot the `-a` in the `cp` command I executed and didn't notice until I rebooted and realized `/home` was owned by root.

Is it somehow possible to give myself all the standard permissions back?
I've thought about one splution, but it would, apparently, cause all programs to have the same permissions as me.

Nautilus says `/home`, and, subsequently, `/home/calin` s owned by root, and that only rooot has permissions.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Thanks in advance.
Cheers.

Comment: Sorry I it looks like you haven't said which command it was that you executed.  I don't think it's really possible to answer this without knowing that.

Comment: You've provided no actual OS & release details; but I'd expect a text login would still work (*even if a GUI session cannot login, as a GUI session requires write access to $HOME and some free space there too*).  Alternatively you can boot a *live* system and mount the partition there & complete whatever you forgot, then reboot & login normally.

Comment: fyi `/home` itself *should* be owned by root, only the individual directories like `/home/calin` should be owned by their users

Comment: @guiverc I did mention the command used, `cp`. — If you mean about what I'm trying to do, I'm trying to do literally anything;  apps like Nautilus won't work because my home dir, `~`, is also owned by root.

Comment: @DanielT It did, technically;  the solution alleviated my issue.  Thank you.

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks for the information; I'll keep that in mind. Though, as I mentioned, both were owned by root.